# Ext Js :: "Error: [Ext.getBody] document.body does not exist at the point " When using Activity Monitor Class?

Tags: extjs

I am sporadically  hitting an error [Ext.getBody] document.body does not exist at the point " in chrome. and in IE.
This is because of using https://github.com/arthurakay/ExtJS-Activity-Monitor/blob/master/Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor

my index.html do have body tags.

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Are you running your `Ext.getBody()` inside of `Ext.application()` or `Ext.onReady()`?

Comment: Ext.Application. Well I using the monitor activity class in my mainController   and the UI:Ext.getBody()  erroring                                          init : function(config) {
        if (!config) { config = {}; }
        
        Ext.apply(this, config, {
            runner     : new Ext.util.TaskRunner(),
            ui         : Ext.getBody(),
            task       : {
                run      : this.monitorUI,
                interval : config.interval || this.interval,
                scope    : this
            }
        });
        
        this.ready = true;
    },

Answer (score 1):

**[Ext.getBody] document.body does not yet exist**

load your bootstrap.js script end of the body in index.html